# A facade root has not been set. in lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

in my get() function from web.php , I am sending the following, and then I get the error "A facade root has not been set."
[image]

Comment: you have to enable facades in Lumen

Answer (score 0):

In your `bootstrap/app.php`, make sure to uncomment

```php
$app->withFacades();
```